# Is there any way to get latitudes and longitudes from Postgres geography type column

Tags: python, postgresql, geometry, psycopg2

I have a column of data type geography in a Postgres table.
[image: Column Data Type]

When I query it from DB it shows like this,

[image: Sample Values]

Now I'm trying to query the table with psycopg2 but instead of the points (lat, long), I'm getting some huge string.
[image]

What is this pattern and How I can cast it to get latitudes and longitudes?

I have tried searching over the internet but unluckily no help found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text representation with the [`dt_astext`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.2/ST_AsText.html) function, or you can type cast to `geometry` and use the [`st_y`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.2/ST_X.html) and [`st_y`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.2/ST_Y.html) functions.

Comment: I tried st_y and st_x and it worked. Thanks

Comment: what if we have coordinates of polygon inside the geography data type then st_y will not work. right?

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the PostGIS documentation, you will find a function to extract vertices as points from a polygon.

Comment: for those who will see this question later,
ST_AsGeoJSON(outdoor_polygon) I used this function to get all vertices of the polygon.
Thanks Laurenz